# Escaping emoji sequences in WPF Textblock

Tags: wpf, unicode, emoji, textblock

I have a textblock that is bound to my 'PostContent' string, like so:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path = PostContent, Mode = OneWay}" FontSize="12" Width="300" Margin = "3 5 3 5"/>
```

My PostContent string will sometimes contain emojis, as well as text. For example I might return a string that looks liks this:

> Hello World `&#x1F600;`

However, the textblock displays the literal string, and does not escape the emoji. I've also tried to escape it like this:

> Hello World \u1F600

But I still end up having the same problem.

Is there another way to escape these chracters properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make this work by taking the hex code (i.e. 1F600) and converting it to a decimal code using the following code:

```
int result = int.Parse(hexCode, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
outputString += char.ConvertFromUtf32(result);
```